# Mapbox Draw (Custom Mode) - Why is changeMode() on draw undefined?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, draw, mapbox-gl

I want to use a custom mode in Mapbox Draw. I declare the draw object like this:

```
  var draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
            polygon: false,
            line_string: true,
            point: false,
            trash: true,
        },
        modes: Object.assign({
            custom_mode: CustomMode,
        }, MapboxDraw.modes),
    });
```

Then I want to change the mode:

```
map.on('load', function () {
    draw.changeMode("custom_mode");
    map.addControl(draw, 'bottom-right');
});
```

Result: Error: Cannot read property 'changeMode' of undefined.
But I can log the draw object just before the changeMode() call.
What is the problem here?

Comment: did you define `toDisplayFeatures` on `CustomMode`?

Comment: yes. I also get the same error message when I want to change to any Mapbox draw mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your object first

```
map.addControl(draw, 'top-left')
```

Comment: Solved it on my end when trying to get DrawRectangle working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your load function add map.addControl above draw.changeMode("custom_mode")